# Promise Wrapping Pattern

Tags: javascript, promise

I currently have the following promise wrapping function:

```
var promiseWrap = (promiseInstance, resolveFunc, rejectFunc) => {
    return new Promise((resolvePath, rejectPath) => {
            promiseInstance
                .then((...args) => {
                    resolvePath(resolveFunc.apply(null, args))
                })
                .catch((...args) => {
                    rejectPath(rejectFunc.apply(null, args))
                })
        });
    }
```

While this works, I get the feeling that it isn't the most efficient way of achieving the desired result, and may even betray a fundamental lack of understanding of how promises work. So this is fairly generic, but how would you refactor this code? Is there even a better way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Better ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: I can't see anything gained by creating `promiseWrap`. It seems redundant with promises natural API.

Comment: (a) Ask on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), (b) You can't rely on people correctly guessing your "desired result" from the code, therefore clearly state it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you just implemented the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) by accident, and are now trying to generalise it, or genuinely recognised the [usefulness of functors/monads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) (congrats!), but **you've reinvented the `.then` method**.

Your code is [more or less exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) equivalent to

```
function promiseWrap(promiseInstance, resolveFunc, rejectFunc) {
    // assuming promiseInstance instanceof Promise - if not, add a `Promise.resolve()`
    return promiseInstance.then(resolveFunc, rejectFunc);
}
```

Indeed, this return value of `then()` calls - another promise for the result of the callback(s) - is what promises are all about.